# JavaScript to find TinyMCE rich text editor value is null or not

Tags: javascript, validation, tinymce, textarea

I use the TinyMCE textarea in one of my web applications.

1. How to check the TinyMCE textarea's value is null or not using JavaScript?

`document.getElementById("myeditorid").value` didn't help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a textarea any more, so the value property won't work.

This is how you get a reference to the editor, and the text from it:

```
var text = tinyMCE.get('myeditorid').getContent();
```

Comment: This is very helpful to me, really thanks to you.. and stackoverflow

Comment: when i am doing this i get the content in html format what should i do to get in the plaintext format.

Comment: @Astrowalker: Hm... The point of using an editor that supports formatting is to get the text with the formatting, you would use a regular `textarea` if you don't want the formatting. If you still want to use an editor and get the text without HTML you would use a regular expression to remove the HTML elements from the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = tinyMCE.get('createSurvey:thankyouMsg_ifr').getContent();
```

here the predefined id was "thankyouMsg"..After the tinyMCe,its id changed to this.I try to get the value in this way but it is not working saying `tinyMCE.get('createSurvey:thankyouMsg_ifr')` is undefined