# .val() works on input but not textarea

Tags: jquery, input, textarea, return-value

I am trying to grab the value entered into the textarea, but it seems to not be working. I tried it again with  instead of  and it seems to be working just fine.

Edit: just realized that this has something to do with tinyMCE. Tried it without tinyMCE and it works fine. Any idea why this is?

```
    $('.answers').load(url, function() {
             tinyMCE.init({ 
                theme : "advanced", 
                mode : "textareas", 
                plugins : "fullpage", 
                theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage" 
              });   

        $('#submitAnswer').on('click', function(e){
            var dataString = $("#addAnswer").val();
                    alert(dataString);
            e.preventDefault();
        });   
    })
```

Doesn't work with:

```
        <textarea id="addAnswer" name="addAnswer"></textarea>
```

Works with:

```
        <input id="addAnswer" name="addAnswer"></input>
```

Comment: Have you tried, `textarea[name=addAnswer]` opposed to `$("#addAnswer").val()`?

Comment: @agassi0430 Please try to reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle, as we cannot guess your exact markup and other js code that may be involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a textarea any more, so the value property won't work.

This is how you get a reference to the editor, and the text from it:

var text = tinyMCE.get('myeditorid').getContent();

[JavaScript to find TinyMCE rich text editor value is null or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122119/javascript-to-find-tinymce-rich-text-editor-value-is-null-or-not?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dataString = $("textarea#addAnswer").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var dataString = $('#addAnswer').text();
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
 var dataString = $('#addAnswer').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.val()` atribute works with textArea.

You can check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6ByK/) for example.

I think your problem is something related with the timing of the events ( ready and load )